# react-router Link is not working

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux

I am trying to create a simple Link in react . here is the code:

```
    import React from 'react';
import { Link }  from 'react-router';
class List extends React.Component{
    render() {
        return (
        <div>
        <p>please choose from repository below.</p>
        <ul>
            <li><Link to={"/react"}>React</Link></li>
        </ul>
        </div>
        );
    }
}

export default List;
```

Here is my package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "chance": "^1.0.9",
    "history": "^4.6.1",
    "react": "^15.5.4",
    "react-dom": "^15.5.4",
    "react-router": "^4.1.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.1.1",
    "superagent": "^3.5.2"
```

I used following command to run my code:

webpack-dev-server

```
bundle.js:1004 Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in. Check the render method of `List`.
    in List (created by Route)
    in Route
    in div
    in Router (created by HashRouter)
    in HashRouter
```

if I remove

```
<li><Link to={"/react"}>React</Link></li>
```

from my code then the page loads properly. Am i using old method of creating Link on component ?

Any hints are appreciated ...

Answer (score 8):

Link is now part of the react-router-dom package. 
so you should change your import to:

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to import `Link` from `react-router-dom`, you can check the example [here](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Link). Also there's no need to use parenthesis, you can simply do: `<Link to="/react">React</Link>`.